# Inline-block span (inside an html td) text-ellipsis fails on long words

Tags: css, html-table

My objective is to have a cell inside a HTML table with an expand button.

This is the html I used:

```
<td>
  <span class='outer'>
    <button>+</button>
    <span class='inner'>Sed eu nisi sit amet</span>
  </span>
</td>
```

The outer span is centered : it contains a button and some text.

The button position is done through absolute positioning on the left of the outer, some left-padding avoid that the text goes under the button.

Everything is fine except when I have a word which doesn't fit inside the td. I thought an overflow:hidden + text-overflow:ellipsis would suffice, but i have a problem.

A demo is available at http://jsfiddle.net/omanovitsh/HYDss/54/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like:

```
.table2 .inner {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 2em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The max-width (or just use width if you prefer) forces the overflow to kick in.

Comment: Actually I have no max-width. If the table is resized and gets larger I want to see my full content

Comment: Ah, I see.  This would be a great time to use calc then :p

Comment: I ended up setting a dynamic max-width with some javascript

Comment: Did you try @media ... in your css to define various max-widths for various screen sizes?

Comment: What is the meaning of em in max-width? I generally see this in the context of font-size. Actually it's working for me but i wanted to know why?

Answer (score 5):

First, generally you want to avoid putting block level elements in inline elements and this is one such case.  See here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#block-inline

Note that: "Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other block-level elements. Generally, inline elements may contain only data and other inline elements. Inherent in this structural distinction is the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline elements."

With regards to the CSS, you would say:

```
.table2 p
{
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

With regards to the HTML, you need to change the `span`s to `div`s:

```
<td>
    <div class='outer'>
        <button>+</button>
        <div class='inner'><p>Sed eu nisi sit ametametamet</p></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Otherwise, setting width to 100% for the `p` element will be unable to fit its width into its parent element since the parent element is a `span` which is an inline element.

Thank you.

Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/VivekVish/HYDss/76/

Comment: Thank you but I need to get the text-overflow: ellipsis working, or if not possible break the long word.

Comment: I altered my answer.  Please tell me if this answers your question.  Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that i cannot impose the width that way. I need the cell content to take all the available width(if the table is resized)

Comment: Gave it my best shot Olivier.  Please see the edits and tell me if it helps.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much you saved my day :-)  I removed the paragraph you added which wasn't necessary to solve my problem (see http://jsfiddle.net/HYDss/87/) it would be nice if you updated your answer accordingly. Bye and thx

Comment: Updated answer in line with your comments.  See you around.

Comment: Your solution breaks my first example (when the outer span must be less large than the table). The outer now being a div, it takes the whole width of its parent. I guess I was too tired to notice it.

Comment: Sadly, this may be a bridge too far.  Every solution that fits the `.inner` element to its content also causes `text-overflow:ellipsis` to fail.  I literally tried every single `display` property on the elements and they all failed.  As far as I know now, you'd have to resort to Javascript to solve this problem.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, I believe you do need the `p` element to make even the normal ellipses work properly.